# htaccess - create a rule for a specific IP?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rule for my IP.

I have a rule that's redirecting all the trafic to a temporary domain, and then I need to create a new rule for making wordpress works fine for me (the permalinks are getting problems because I changed the htaccess to redirect people.

here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^95.126.000.MYIP
RewriteRule $ http://www.tempraldomain.com [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I need to mix first block with the second to work properly.
Any helping soul?

Comment: edit: .. the second to work properly ONLY FOR MY IP

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question completely, but I think this might be what your looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^95\.126\.000\.MYIP$
RewriteRule $ http://www.tempraldomain.com [R=302,L]


RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^95\.126\.000\.MYIP$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```